# Не могу сделать рандомное число в WinForms c++

Tags: winforms, случайные-числа, c++-cli

Хочу сделать рандомное изменение скорости от 2 до 5 (точный интервал пока не установил).

Делаю все правильно: подключил библиотеки (windows.h ; ctime ; random и т.д.)
Но в строчке указывается ошибка на time:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Сама ошибка: Выражение перед скобками вероятного вызова должно иметь тип функции (pointer-to-)

Вот полная функция:

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
int x;
bool car1Stop = false;

if ((car1->Left + car1->Width) < label1->Left) {
    srand(time(0));
    x = rand() % 6;
    car1->Left += x;
}
else {
    short d = x;
    car1Stop = true;
    timer1->Enabled = false;
}
```

}

Я знаю, что есть возможность работы с дистрибьюторами, но хотелось бы попроще, если есть возможность, заранее спасибо!

Comment: _Делаю все правильно_ - нет. Вы делаете всё неправильно. Начнём с того, что вы взяли язык C++/CLI. Этот язык не используется для написания приложений. Но если уж вы вляпались в него, то используйте возможности платформы .NET. Смотрите класс [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random).

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку `random`, а чтобы получить случайное число от `a` до `b` писать `rand() % (b - a + 1) + a`, в частности `rand() % m` возвращает случайное число от 0 до m - 1.

Comment: Благодарю, эта функция действительно помогает, но при повторном запуске программы значения идут в том же порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Все же решил использовать библиотеку random, алгоритм Mersenne twister и дистрибьютор целых чисел! НО, если кто-то знает, как решить вопрос без использования библиотеки random, ответьте пожалуйста!

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).